# Play sound file on Qt+Mac

Tags: qt, macos, audio

I need to play sounds under Qt with control of volume and panning. QSound doesn't do it, phonon may be too much for only this so I thought I'd try the native api.

eeermm, in Mac I have no idea, is there some simple interface to invoke on c++? (I've seen all this NSSound stuff but I am not familar with Objective C and I am not sure if it's possible to mix code (under QtCreator)) my idea would be to a module with simple native api calls to system features not found on Qt.

Thanks!

Comment: As you've probably discovered, QSound is fairly basic, designed for simply playing an audio file and not much else. But why do you think Phonon is "too much" if it gets the job done, or are you constricted by other constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt AudioEngine in Qt5 will do this.

If you're using Qt4, making a single 'Objective-C++' file (extension .mm) which can be called from Qt, but makes NSFoo calls, is easy and works well. The header file should be plain C++, and everything will work together.